# How to replace node_form() with my custom form callback?

Tags: 7, forms

In my module, I want to override the call to `node_form()` for a specific node type called `superpage`, because I want this specific node form to allow for a confirmation step before saving.

In `drupal_retrieve_form()`, every node form is built by the function `node_form()`, which adds everything you'd expect from a node form.

I want to add an extra step to my form: First, the node form should be rendered normally; then, when the user clicks *Save*, I am using a *custom submit handler* to set `$form_state['rebuild']`, and to set a custom flag, signaling the need for confirmation. Now I want to rebuild the form not through `node_form()`; instead I want to display a `confirm_form()`.

This means that the process starts over in `drupal_retrieve_form()`, which simply calls `node_form()` again, because the `node` module implements `hook_forms()` and defines that callback for all node forms.

I would like to replace the form callback for my custom content type, so that it returns a normal node form if confirmation is not needed, or a confirmation form if needed.

Implementing `hook_forms()` in my module didn't help.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_forms().
 */
function superpages_forms($form_id, $args) {
  $forms = array();
  if ($form_id == 'superpage_node_form') {
    // Adding this callback crashes drupal_retrieve_form().
    $forms[$form_id]['callback'] = 'superpages_wrapped_node_form';
  }
  return $forms;
}

function superpages_wrapped_node_form($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  // Build for special case: a confirmation form.
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['confirm_is_needed'])) {
    $confirm = t('You should be careful with this. Are you sure?');
    $confirm_form = confirm_form(array(), $confirm, 'node/' . $node->nid);
    return $confirm_form;
  } else {
  // Build a normal node form.
    return node_form($form, $form_state, $node);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1. You can use hook_menu_alter and you can set your callback

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/add/superpage']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_superpage_form';
}
```

Variant 2. You can use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter  and override/edit the form

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_form_superpage_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with Variant 1, it should take less effort.